# How many coefficients in $(x_1 +x_2 + \cdots + x_L)^N$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many  coefficients in $(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_L)^N$?
That is to say, what is the  number of coefficients when it represents as sum of products.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine a general formula that will reveal why, for instance, $(a + b + c)^2$ has six terms?

Answer (score 3):

Each term will be of the form $c\cdot x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_L^{a_L}$ with the property that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_L = N$ and each $a_i\in \{0,1,\dots,N\}$

The problem then reworded is "*How many selections of $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_L)$ satisfy the above property?*"

Approach via [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).  This is the same question as "*how many ways can you distribute $N$ identical cookies among $L$ children?*"